# How do you convert a time offset to a location/timezone in Go

Tags: go, timezone

Given an arbitrary time offset, how does one go about creating a usable `time.Location` object that represents that time offset?

The following [code](https://play.golang.org/p/j_E28qJ8Vgy) parses a time using an offset, but `fmt.Println(t.Location())` subsequently returns no information:

```
func main() {
    offset := "+1100"

    t, err := time.Parse("15:04 GMT-0700","15:06 GMT"+offset)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("fail", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
    fmt.Println(t.UTC())
    fmt.Println(t.Location())
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/j_E28qJ8Vgy

Basically I have some time data with time offsets, but without location data, I want to create a `time.Location` object to ensure the GMT offset is recorded. And then be able to output the time relative to the end users actual location time offset.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/time/#FixedZone

Comment: When you say "relative to the end users actual location time offset" do you mean such as with regard to their local time including daylight saving?  If so - that's not possible (in any language).  In other words, if all one has is `UTC+2`, then you cannot know whether it belongs to `Africa/Cairo` or `Asia/Jersalem` or `Europe/Helsinki`, or various other places, which may or may not be in UTC+1, UTC+2, or UTC+3 at a given point in time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
loc := time.FixedZone("UTC+11", +11*60*60)
```

Then set to this location:

```
t = t.In(loc)
```

Try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/KfzeJMGs7Ug):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    loc := time.FixedZone("UTC+11", +11*60*60)

    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(t)
    fmt.Println(t.Location())

    t = t.In(loc)
    fmt.Println(t)
    fmt.Println(t.Location())

    fmt.Println(t.UTC())
    fmt.Println(t.Location())
}
```

Output:

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC m=+0.000000001
UTC
2009-11-11 10:00:00 +1100 UTC+11
UTC+11
2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC
UTC+11
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if len(offset) == 5 {
    hours, ok1 := strconv.ParseInt(offset[:3], 10, 0)
    mins, ok2 := strconv.ParseInt(offset[3:5], 10, 0)
    if ok1 == nil && ok2 == nil {
        t = t.In(time.FixedZone("Fixed", int((hours*60+mins)*60)))
        fmt.Println(t)
        fmt.Println(t.Location())
    }
}
```